# Tensorflow - how to modify tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train a ResNet50 classifier using Tensorflow

Let's say there are 10 classes (label 0-9) and current label is 7. 
The one-hot encoding of this label will be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`.
 However, I want to modify this label to be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 0.1]` so the network is punished less when it guesses 6 or 8 when its supposed to true label is 7.

I am using tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator and I wasn't sure how to modify the labels there so I decided to modify the labels in my training loop.

Train loop:

```
num_train_batches = len(train_ds)
num_train_step = 0
for images, labels in train_ds:
    train_step(images, labels)
    num_train_step += 1
    if num_train_step==num_train_batches:
        break
```

Train step:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        preds = model(images, training=True)
        loss = my_loss(labels, preds)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    # update metrics
    train_loss(loss)
    train_accuracy(labels, preds)
```

my_loss: one hot encoding labels and applying my_labelize to each onehot encoded label

```
def my_loss(labels, preds): # labels is not one hot encoded
    x = 0
    oh_labels = tf.one_hot(K.cast(labels, dtype='int32'), 10, dtype=tf.float32)
    my_labels = tf.map_fn(fn=my_labelize, elems=oh_labels)

    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=my_labels, logits=[preds])
    return loss
```

my_labelize: I am creating 3 separate arrays ([left of 1], [1], [right of 1]) and concatenating all 3
In above example with label 7, left will be [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.8] and right will be [0.8, 0.1]

```
def my_labelize(oh_row): # oh_row will be one hot encoded vector 
    idx = tf.where(tf.equal(oh_row, 1))[0] # supposed to find index where 1 is 

    left_zero_idx = idx-3
    second_left = idx-2
    first_left = idx-1

    if first_left < 0:
        left = np.array([])
    elif second_left < 0:
        left = np.array([0.8])
    elif left_zero_idx < 0:
        left = np.array([0.1, 0.8])
    else:
        left = np.append(np.zeros(left_zero_idx+1), np.array([0.1, 0.8]))
    
    right_zero_idx = idx+3
    second_right = idx+2
    first_right = idx+1

    if first_right > len(oh_row):
        right = np.array([])
    elif second_right > len(oh_row):
        right = np.array([0.8])
    elif right_zero_idx > len(oh_row):
        right = np.array([0.8, 0.1])
    else:
        right = np.append(np.array([0.8, 0.1]), np.zeros(len(oh_row)-right_zero_idx))
    
    left = tf.convert_to_tensor(left, tf.float32)
    mid = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([1]), tf.float32)
    right = tf.convert_to_tensor(right, tf.float32)
    my_label = tf.stack([left, mid, right])
    return my_label
```

However this does not seem to be working (mostly erors in my_labelize, the values don't seem to be updating properly or getting None) and when I'm trying to debug by checking values in debugger mode I only get outputs like `Tensor("map/while/strided_slice:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int64). When I try to use .eval() I get this error

> ValueError: Cannot use the default session to evaluate tensor: the
> tensor's graph is different from the session's graph. Pass an explicit
> session to `eval(session=sess)`.

What is the best way to replace values at a given index of a tensor? I know tensor values can't be changed so I would have to crate a copy, but I'm not sure what the fastest way is (without losing GPU acceleration)

Comment: try `.numpy()` for debugging, `tensor_scatter_nd_update` for updating. And please split your question by two. Multiple questions are treated as not focused here and can be closed

Comment: thank you, tensor_scatter_nd_update was the function I was looking for